# DeleteCriticalSection could not locate dll

Tags: c++, dll, terminfo

I am trying to recompile an old Win32 software package in order to bring small modifications.
The package is part of the MT SDK from Xsens and allows to get output from a inertial sensor (available here https://content.xsens.com/hubfs/Downloads/Software/mtsdk3.3_setup.zip). Example of a C++ routine using a DLL file responsible for the communication with hardware is located in Program Files\Xsens\MT SDK\Software Developpement\Examples\CMT Example Dll.

From directory I recompiled the source code, linking the DLL such as

```
i686-w64-mingw32-g++ -o test main.cpp -L. -lxsens_cmt
```

It requires changing a few `scanf_s` calls to `scanf` but compiled properly into test.exe.

However, when I try to run that executable in Windows I get the following error:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PVqmB.png)

On the net I could find recommendation to compile with the following options but none could resolve my issue :

- `-static`
- `-static-libstdc++`
- `-static-libgcc`

Examples folder of the MTSDK can be downloaded here if you don't want to install the software :
https://gitlab.com/lenhofed/mtsdk_modifs.git

**main.cpp**

```
/* demo key, replace this key with your own */
#define KEY "b8r6RCoGjQJVsytwUMo8WCRiJiVCCdoL11cCj4HqnaKPHtTn"


#include <stdio.h>      // Needed for printf etc
#include <objbase.h>    // Needed for COM functionality
#include "xsens_cmt.h"
#include <conio.h>      // included for _getch and _kbhit
#include "main.h"


// this macro tests for an error and exits the program with a message if there was one
#define EXIT_ON_ERROR(res,comment) if (res != XRV_OK) { printf("Error %d occurred in " comment ": %s\n",res,cmtGetResultText(res)); exit(1); }

long instance = -1;
// used to signal that the user initiated the exit, so we do not wait for an extra keypress-
int userQuit = 0;
CmtOutputMode mode;
CmtOutputSettings settings;
unsigned short mtCount = 0;
int screenSensorOffset = 0;
int temperatureOffset = 0;
CmtDeviceId deviceIds[256];
CmtVector positionLLA;



int main(void)
{
    XsensResultValue res = XRV_OK;
    short screenSkipFactor = 10;
    short screenSkipFactorCnt = screenSkipFactor;
    
    // Set exit function
    atexit(exitFunc);

    // lets create the Xsens CMT instance to handle the sensor(s)
    printf("Creating an XsensCMT instance\n");

    char serialNumber[] = KEY;
    if (strcmp(serialNumber,"b8r6RCoGjQJVsytwUMo8WCRiJiVCCdoL11cCj4HqnaKPHtTn") == 0)
        printf("Warning: Using the demo key as a serial code will limit CMT functionality to 1000 calls. Enter your own serial code for unlimited CMT functionality.\n");

    instance = cmtCreateInstance(serialNumber);
    if (instance != -1)
        printf("CMT instance created\n\n");
    else {
        printf("Creation of CMT instance failed, probably because of an invalid serial number\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    // Perform hardware scan
    doHardwareScan();

    // Give user a (short) chance to see hardware scan results
    Sleep(2000);
    
    //clear screen present & get the user output mode selection.
    clrscr();
    getUserInputs();

    // Set device to user input settings
    doMtSettings();
    
    // Wait for first data item(s) to arrive. In production code, you would use a callback function instead (see cmtRegisterCallback function)
    Sleep(20);

    //get the placement offsets, clear the screen and write the fixed headers.
    calcScreenOffset();
    clrscr();
    writeHeaders();

    // vars for sample counter & temp.
    unsigned short sdata;
    double tdata;
    
    //structs to hold data.
    CmtCalData caldata;
    CmtQuat qat_data;
    CmtEuler euler_data;
    CmtMatrix matrix_data;
    
    while(!userQuit && res == XRV_OK)
    {
        //get the bundle of data
        res = cmtGetNextDataBundle(instance);
        Sleep(10);
    
        //get sample count, goto position & display.
        res = cmtDataGetSampleCounter(instance, &sdata, deviceIds[0] ,NULL);
        gotoxy(0,0);
        printf("Sample Counter %05hu\n", sdata);

        if (screenSkipFactorCnt++ == screenSkipFactor) {
            screenSkipFactorCnt = 0;

            for (unsigned int i = 0; i < mtCount; i++) {    
                // Output Temperature
                if ((mode & CMT_OUTPUTMODE_TEMP) != 0) {                    
                    gotoxy(0,4 + i * screenSensorOffset);   
                    res = cmtDataGetTemp(instance,  &tdata, deviceIds[i],NULL);
                    printf("%6.2f", tdata);
                }

                gotoxy(0,5 + temperatureOffset + i * screenSensorOffset);   // Output Calibrated data
                if ((mode & CMT_OUTPUTMODE_CALIB) != 0) {
                    
                    res = cmtDataGetCalData(instance, &caldata, deviceIds[i]);
                    printf("%6.2f\t%6.2f\t%6.2f" , caldata.m_acc.m_data[0], caldata.m_acc.m_data[1], caldata.m_acc.m_data[2]);

                    gotoxy(0,7 + temperatureOffset + i * screenSensorOffset);
                    printf("%6.2f\t%6.2f\t%6.2f", caldata.m_gyr.m_data[0], caldata.m_gyr.m_data[1], caldata.m_gyr.m_data[2] );

                    gotoxy(0,9 + temperatureOffset + i * screenSensorOffset);
                    printf("%6.2f\t%6.2f\t%6.2f",caldata.m_mag.m_data[0], caldata.m_mag.m_data[1], caldata.m_mag.m_data[2]);
                    gotoxy(0,13 + temperatureOffset + i * screenSensorOffset);
                }

                if ((mode & CMT_OUTPUTMODE_ORIENT) != 0) {                  
                    switch(settings & CMT_OUTPUTSETTINGS_ORIENTMODE_MASK) {
                    case CMT_OUTPUTSETTINGS_ORIENTMODE_QUATERNION:
                        // Output: quaternion
                        res = cmtDataGetOriQuat(instance, &qat_data, deviceIds[i]);
                        printf("%6.3f\t%6.3f\t%6.3f\t%6.3f\n", qat_data.m_data[0], qat_data.m_data[1],qat_data.m_data[2],qat_data.m_data[3]);
                        break;

                    case CMT_OUTPUTSETTINGS_ORIENTMODE_EULER:
                        // Output: Euler
                        res = cmtDataGetOriEuler(instance, &euler_data, deviceIds[i]);
                        printf("%6.1f\t%6.1f\t%6.1f\n", euler_data.m_roll,euler_data.m_pitch, euler_data.m_yaw);
                        break;

                    case CMT_OUTPUTSETTINGS_ORIENTMODE_MATRIX:
                        // Output: Cosine Matrix
                        res = cmtDataGetOriMatrix(instance, &matrix_data, deviceIds[i],NULL);
                        printf("%6.3f\t%6.3f\t%6.3f\n", matrix_data.m_data[0][0],matrix_data.m_data[0][1], matrix_data.m_data[0][2]);
                        printf("%6.3f\t%6.3f\t%6.3f\n", matrix_data.m_data[1][0],matrix_data.m_data[1][1], matrix_data.m_data[1][2]);
                        printf("%6.3f\t%6.3f\t%6.3f\n", matrix_data.m_data[2][0],matrix_data.m_data[2][1], matrix_data.m_data[2][2]);
                        break;
                    default:
                        ;
                    }
                }

                if ((mode & CMT_OUTPUTMODE_POSITION) != 0) {
                    /* output position */
                    printf("\n\n");
                    if (cmtDataContainsPositionLLA(instance, deviceIds[i]) != 0) {
                        res = cmtDataGetPositionLLA(instance, &positionLLA, deviceIds[i]);
                        if (res != XRV_OK) {
                            printf("error %ud", res);
                        }

                        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
                            double deg = positionLLA.m_data[i];
                            double min = (deg - (int)deg)*60;
                            double sec = (min - (int)min)*60;
                            printf("%3d\xa7%2d\'%2.2lf\"\t", (int)deg, (int)min, sec);
                        }
                        printf(" %3.2lf\n", positionLLA.m_data[2]);
                    } else {
                        printf("No position data available\n");
                    }
                }    
            }   
        }               

        if (_kbhit())
            userQuit = 1;
    }

    clrscr();
    cmtClose(instance);

    return 0;
}

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// doHardwareScan
//
// Checks available COM ports and scans for MotionTrackers
void doHardwareScan()
{
    XsensResultValue res;
    CmtPortInfo portInfo[256];
    uint32_t portCount = 0;

    printf("Scanning for connected Xsens devices...");
    res = cmtScanPorts(portInfo, &portCount, 0);
    EXIT_ON_ERROR(res,"cmtScanPorts");
    printf("done\n");

    if (portCount == 0) {
        printf("No MotionTrackers found\n\n");
        exit(0);
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < (int)portCount; i++) {   
        printf("Using COM port %d at %d baud\n\n",
            (long) portInfo[i].m_portNr, portInfo[i].m_baudrate);   
    }
    
    printf("Opening ports...");
    //open the port which the device is connected to and connect at the device's baudrate.
    for(int p = 0; p < (int)portCount; p++){
        res = cmtOpenPort(instance, portInfo[p].m_portNr, portInfo[p].m_baudrate);
        EXIT_ON_ERROR(res,"cmtOpenPort");  
    }
    printf("done\n\n");

    //get the Mt sensor count.
    printf("Retrieving MotionTracker count (excluding attached Xbus Master(s))\n");
    res = cmtGetMtCount(instance,&mtCount);
    EXIT_ON_ERROR(res,"cmtGetMtCount");
    printf("MotionTracker count: %i\n\n",mtCount);

    // retrieve the device IDs 
    printf("Retrieving MotionTrackers device ID(s)\n");
    for(unsigned int j = 0; j < mtCount; j++ ){
        res = cmtGetMtDeviceId(instance, &deviceIds[j], j);
        EXIT_ON_ERROR(res,"cmtGetDeviceId");
        printf("Device ID at index %i: %08x\n",j,(long) deviceIds[j]);
    }   

    // make sure that we get the freshest data
    printf("\nSetting queue mode so that we always get the latest data\n\n");
    res = cmtSetQueueMode(instance,CMT_QM_LAST);
    EXIT_ON_ERROR(res,"cmtSetQueueMode");
}

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// getUserInputs
//
// Request user for output data
void getUserInputs()
{
    mode = 0;
    while (mode < 1 || mode > 6) {
        printf("Select desired output:\n");
        printf("1 - Calibrated data\n");
        printf("2 - Orientation data and GPS Position (MTi-G only)\n");
        printf("3 - Both Calibrated and Orientation data\n");
        printf("4 - Temperature and Calibrated data\n");
        printf("5 - Temperature and Orientation data\n");
        printf("6 - Temperature, Calibrated and Orientation data\n");
        printf("Enter your choice: ");
        scanf("%d", &mode);
        // flush stdin
        while (getchar() != '\n') continue;

        if (mode < 1 || mode > 6) {
            printf("\n\nPlease enter a valid output mode\n");
        }
    }
    clrscr();

    switch(mode)
    {
    case 1:
        mode = CMT_OUTPUTMODE_CALIB;
        break;
    case 2:
        mode = CMT_OUTPUTMODE_ORIENT | CMT_OUTPUTMODE_POSITION;
        break;
    case 3:
        mode = CMT_OUTPUTMODE_CALIB | CMT_OUTPUTMODE_ORIENT;
        break;
    case 4:
        mode = CMT_OUTPUTMODE_TEMP | CMT_OUTPUTMODE_CALIB;
        break;
    case 5:
        mode = CMT_OUTPUTMODE_TEMP | CMT_OUTPUTMODE_ORIENT;
        break;
    case 6:
        mode = CMT_OUTPUTMODE_TEMP | CMT_OUTPUTMODE_CALIB | CMT_OUTPUTMODE_ORIENT;
        break;
    }

    if ((mode & CMT_OUTPUTMODE_ORIENT) != 0) {
        do{
            printf("Select desired output format\n");
            printf("1 - Quaternions\n");
            printf("2 - Euler angles\n");
            printf("3 - Matrix\n");
            printf("Enter your choice: ");
            scanf("%d", &settings);
            // flush stdin
            while (getchar() != '\n') continue;

            if (settings < 1  || settings > 3) {
                printf("\n\nPlease enter a valid choice\n");
            }
        }while(settings < 1 || settings > 3);

        // Update outputSettings to match data specs of SetOutputSettings
        switch(settings) {
        case 1:
            settings = CMT_OUTPUTSETTINGS_ORIENTMODE_QUATERNION;
            break;
        case 2:
            settings = CMT_OUTPUTSETTINGS_ORIENTMODE_EULER;
            break;
        case 3:
            settings = CMT_OUTPUTSETTINGS_ORIENTMODE_MATRIX;
            break;
        }
    }
    else{
        settings = 0;
    }
    settings |= CMT_OUTPUTSETTINGS_TIMESTAMP_SAMPLECNT;
}

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// doMTSettings
//
// Set user settings in MTi/MTx
// Assumes initialized global MTComm class
void doMtSettings(void) 
{
    XsensResultValue res;

    // set sensor to config sate
    res = cmtGotoConfig(instance);
    EXIT_ON_ERROR(res, "cmtGotoConfig");

    unsigned short sampleFreq;
    res = cmtGetSampleFrequency(instance, &sampleFreq, deviceIds[0]);

    // set the device output mode for the device(s)
    printf("Configuring your mode selection");
    for (int i=0; i < mtCount; i++) {
        if (cmtIdIsMtig(deviceIds[i])) {
            res = cmtSetDeviceMode(instance, mode,settings, sampleFreq, deviceIds[i]);
        } else {
            res = cmtSetDeviceMode(instance, mode & 0xFF0F, settings, sampleFreq, deviceIds[i]);
        }
        EXIT_ON_ERROR(res, "setDeviceMode");
    }

    // start receiving data
    res = cmtGotoMeasurement(instance);
    EXIT_ON_ERROR(res, "cmtGotoMeasurement");
}

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// writeHeaders
//
// Write appropriate headers to screen
void writeHeaders()
{
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < mtCount; i++) {    
        gotoxy(0, 2 + i * screenSensorOffset);
        printf("MotionTracker %d\n", i + 1);

        if ((mode & CMT_OUTPUTMODE_TEMP) != 0) {
            temperatureOffset = 3;
            gotoxy(0,3 + i * screenSensorOffset);
            printf("Temperature");
            gotoxy(7,4 + i * screenSensorOffset);
            printf("degrees celcius");
            gotoxy(0,6 + i * screenSensorOffset);
        }

        if ((mode & CMT_OUTPUTMODE_CALIB) != 0) {
            gotoxy(0,3 + temperatureOffset + i * screenSensorOffset);
            printf("Calibrated sensor data");
            gotoxy(0,4 + temperatureOffset + i * screenSensorOffset);
            printf(" Acc X\t Acc Y\t Acc Z");
            gotoxy(23, 5 + temperatureOffset + i * screenSensorOffset);
            printf("(m/s^2)");
            gotoxy(0,6 + temperatureOffset + i * screenSensorOffset);
            printf(" Gyr X\t Gyr Y\t Gyr Z");
            gotoxy(23, 7 + temperatureOffset + i * screenSensorOffset);
            printf("(rad/s)");
            gotoxy(0,8 + temperatureOffset + i * screenSensorOffset);
            printf(" Mag X\t Mag Y\t Mag Z");
            gotoxy(23, 9 + temperatureOffset + i * screenSensorOffset);
            printf("(a.u.)");
            gotoxy(0,11 + temperatureOffset + i * screenSensorOffset);
        }

        if ((mode & CMT_OUTPUTMODE_ORIENT) != 0) {
            printf("Orientation data\n");
            switch(settings & CMT_OUTPUTSETTINGS_ORIENTMODE_MASK) {
            case CMT_OUTPUTSETTINGS_ORIENTMODE_QUATERNION:
                printf("    q0\t    q1\t    q2\t    q3\n");
                break;
            case CMT_OUTPUTSETTINGS_ORIENTMODE_EULER:
                printf("  Roll\t Pitch\t   Yaw\n");
                printf("                       degrees\n");
                break;
            case CMT_OUTPUTSETTINGS_ORIENTMODE_MATRIX:
                printf(" Matrix\n");
                break;
            default:
                ;
            }           
        }

        if ((mode & CMT_OUTPUTMODE_POSITION) != 0) {
            printf("\nLongitude\tLatitude\t Altitude\n");
        }
    }
}

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// calcScreenOffset
//
// Calculates offset for screen data with multiple sensors.
void calcScreenOffset()
{
    // 1 line for "Sensor ..."
    screenSensorOffset += 1;
    if ((mode & CMT_OUTPUTMODE_TEMP) != 0)
        screenSensorOffset += 3;
    if ((mode & CMT_OUTPUTMODE_CALIB) != 0)
        screenSensorOffset += 8;
    if ((mode & CMT_OUTPUTMODE_ORIENT) != 0) {
        switch(settings & CMT_OUTPUTSETTINGS_ORIENTMODE_MASK) {
        case CMT_OUTPUTSETTINGS_ORIENTMODE_QUATERNION:
            screenSensorOffset += 4;
            break;
        case CMT_OUTPUTSETTINGS_ORIENTMODE_EULER:
            screenSensorOffset += 4;
            break;
        case CMT_OUTPUTSETTINGS_ORIENTMODE_MATRIX:
            screenSensorOffset += 6;
            break;
        default:
            ;
        }
    if ((mode & CMT_OUTPUTMODE_POSITION) != 0)
        screenSensorOffset += 4;
    }
}

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// clrscr
//
// Clear console screen
void clrscr() 
{
#ifdef WIN32
    CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO csbi;
    HANDLE hStdOut = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    COORD coord = {0, 0};
    DWORD count;

    GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(hStdOut, &csbi);
    FillConsoleOutputCharacter(hStdOut, ' ', csbi.dwSize.X * csbi.dwSize.Y, coord, &count);
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(hStdOut, coord);
#else
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        // Insert new lines to create a blank screen
        putchar('\n');
    gotoxy(0,0);
#endif
}

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// gotoxy
//
// Sets the cursor position at the specified console position
//
// Input
//   x  : New horizontal cursor position
//   y  : New vertical cursor position
void gotoxy(int x, int y)
{
#ifdef WIN32
    COORD coord;
    coord.X = x;
    coord.Y = y;
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), coord);
#else
    char essq[100];     // String variable to hold the escape sequence
    char xstr[100];     // Strings to hold the x and y coordinates
    char ystr[100];     // Escape sequences must be built with characters

    /*
    ** Convert the screen coordinates to strings
    */
    sprintf(xstr, "%d", x);
    sprintf(ystr, "%d", y);

    /*
    ** Build the escape sequence (vertical move)
    */
    essq[0] = '\0';
    strcat(essq, "\033[");
    strcat(essq, ystr);

    /*
    ** Described in man terminfo as vpa=\E[%p1%dd
    ** Vertical position absolute
    */
    strcat(essq, "d");

    /*
    ** Horizontal move
    ** Horizontal position absolute
    */
    strcat(essq, "\033[");
    strcat(essq, xstr);
    // Described in man terminfo as hpa=\E[%p1%dG
    strcat(essq, "G");

    /*
    ** Execute the escape sequence
    ** This will move the cursor to x, y
    */
    printf("%s", essq);
#endif
}

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// exitFunc
//
// Closes cmt nicely
void exitFunc(void)
{
    // if we have a valid instance, we should get rid of it at the end of the program
    if (instance != -1) {
        // Close any open COM ports
        cmtClose(instance);     
        cmtDestroyInstance(instance);
    }

    // get rid of keystrokes before we post our message
    while (_kbhit()) _getch();

    // wait for a keypress
    if (!userQuit)
    {
        //printf("Press a key to exit\n");
        //_getch();
    }
}
```

**main.h**

```
void doHardwareScan();
void doMtSettings(void);
void getUserInputs(void);
void clrscr(void);
void writeHeaders(void);
void gotoxy(int x, int y);
void calcScreenOffset(void);
void exitFunc(void);
```

Comment: [`DeleteCriticalSection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-deletecriticalsection) is a WinAPI function found in the Windows Kernel

Comment: The screen shot of the error message is strange for 2 reasons: (1) the program seems to think that `test.exe` is a DLL and (2) the program should be looking for the entry point in `Kernel32.dll` and not in some _"random"_ program.

Comment: Don't add the answer in the question. Write an answer to your own question instead.

Comment: After some research I learned that my error could be caused by a file corruption somewhere. So I downloaded and reinstall the software where the original piece of codes are from, just in case...

Then I checked that my dll linking is correct, following :
https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/WIN32.html

Renaming my dll such as libxsens_cmt.dll.a and running :

    `i686-w64-mingw32-g++ -o test -L./ -lxsens_cmt main.cpp`

finally solved my executable problem.